# Using _.bindAll in Backbone.Model

Tags: backbone.js, this, underscore.js

I am still very confused on *how* to use [`_.bindAll()`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll). I understand that **this** sometimes refers to another object and thus we need to use `_.bindAll()` to correct it.

For example, here I can't use `this.setLevelTimer(false)`, because `this` is pointing `setTimeout`, so where do I put the `_.bindAll()`.

What if there is more than one instance that `this` is not pointing correctly. Do I use multiple `_.bindAll()`s?

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){

    }
    ...
    setLevelTimer : function (){

        if (delta < 0){
             this.gameOver();
        } else {
            gameState.timer = setTimeout(function(){
                return this.setLevelTimer(false);  //"this" does not work
            }, 30);
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_.bindAll binds the this object to be the initialized object for the **function scope**.

If you have nested scopes inside the function, the this object may be different.

For example

```
setLevelTimer: function(){
  // this should equal to the initialized model
  $("a").click(function(){
    // the this variable here is the clicked DOM object - not the initialized model
  });
}
```

A common solution to this problem is setting a that variable on the first line of the function, then you can use it inside nested scopes as well (as long as it's not being redefined again of course), for example:

```
setLevelTimer: function(){
  // this should equal to the initialized model
  var that = this;
  $("a").click(function(){
    // the that variable here is the initialized model
  });
}
```

Comment: I understand that part, so say the above `return this.setLevelTimer`, how would I correct `this`. Would I use `.bindAll` right at the beginning of the `setLevelTimer` function? I tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: got it. thanks. the above is just some random code i have. but i understand from your example how to avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

`_.bindAll` binds the given objects function properties' `this` to the given object. [Docs](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll), [source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-53)

What you're doing is supposing that `this` is set correctly within the anonymous function you supply to `setTimeout`, but how can that be, as that anonymous function is not a function property of your Model.

This is why you have to provide the anonymous function with the correct `this`, there are at least these 2 ways:

```
var self = this; // store correct this into a variable
gameState.timer = setTimeout(function(){
     return self.setLevelTimer(false); 
}, 30);
```

or

```
// use bind to bind your anonymous functio to the right this
gameState.timer = setTimeout(_.bind(function(){ 
   return this.setLevelTimer(false); 
}, this), 30);
```

Hope this helps (and clears things out for you)!

P.S.

As to answer your original question. This problem is not the fault of `_.bindAll`, you should use `_.bindAll(this)` within your `initialize` -function to keep the Backbone object's functions bound to the correct `this`, but as bindAll doesn't affect the anonymous function you create on the fly, you need to use other measures (some of which I described above) to keep them bound to the `this` you want.